# Need to trim a xml content from Aadhar scanned data

Tags: android, xml-parsing

I'm trying to scan an Aadhar card data and trying to parse the given data into my app. I'm getting the response as follows.

```
QR-Code:<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <PrintLetterBarcodeData uid=“xxxxxxx” name=“xx” gender=“XXXX” yob=“xxxx” co="S/O: XXXX” house=“XXXX house” street="null" lm="null" loc="null" vtc=“xxx” po=“xxx” dist=“xxx” subdist=“xxx” state=“xxx” pc=“xxx” dob=“xxxx-xx-xx”/>
```

I need to trim the content  `QR-Code:<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>.` 
Is it possible?

Comment: Instead of trimming parse the xml response. That would be better to handle

Answer (score 0):

Split using ":" then parse the remaining XML

```
String[] data = result.split(":");
    String xml = data[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public String trimStart(String qrCodeScanResponse){
    return qrCodeScanResponse.replace("QR-Code:<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>","");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// 'c' contains your xml data
var currLoanXml = c;
var uid = $(currLoanXml).filter('PrintLetterBarcodeData').attr('uid');
document.getElementById('aadhar').value=uid;
```

Here I chosen uid number, you can choose any attribute as per your need